# Start a virtualenv inside a shell script

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv

I'm working on a Python project that's wrapped in a virtualenv. I'd like to have a script that does all the "footwork" of getting set up as soon as I clone my git repo -- namely make the virtualenv, download my requirements, and **stay in the virtualenv after exiting**. However, once the shell script finishes, I'm no longer in my virtualenv, since the changes it makes to its shell don't propagate to mine.

How can I have the virtualenv "stick" to the parent shell that ran the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function instead of a separate script. A function executes in the context of your current shell.

Comment: Would that require adding a function to my .bash_profile that hardcodes the layout of my current project?

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it. You could put it in a separate filr and `source` it from your `.bash_profile` as well; if it's complex, maybe that's the way to go. Whether you hard-code or parametrize paths etc is obviously up to you.

Comment: It's 10ish lines long and extremely localized to the current app, it's not something that I want running around in my environment on a day-to-day basis. I guess you're saying I could wrap it in a function, `source` the script, then execute the function, but I was hoping for a "press one button and go" solution.

Comment: You can make it two-stage -- define a simple function in your `.bashrc` which pulls in the real thing when you want it, kind of like the `activate` of `virtualenv`.

Comment: That still doesn't give me something I can `git clone` into a fresh EC2 instance and get up and running instantly.